# Examples of Hermitian matrices that satisfy properties

Tags: linear-algebra

> Give examples of matrices $A,B\in\mathbf{C}^n$ that satisfy the following properties, or  prove that such matrix does not exist:
>
> - $\overline{A}^\top=A$, and there exists a basis of $\mathbf{C}^n$ consisting of non-orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$
> - $\overline{B}^\top\neq B$, all eigenvalues of $B$ are real, and eigenvectors of $B$ that belong to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Fo rthe first one, I think it is possible, but I can't think of an example.

For the second one, I don't think such matrix exists, since the properties define an Hermitian matrix. I am not able to prove it though.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $A = I$ the identity matrix, with any non-orthogonal basis. Any example will involve repeated eigenvalues like this, because otherwise it's impossible by the spectral theorem.
- Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues along the diagonal, and let $P$ be a matrix with columns a corresponding orthonormal eigenbasis. Then $B = PD\overline{P}^T$ satisfies $\overline{B}^T = B$.